# Is it bad for a CPU to be running at a high speed for extended periods of time?

Tags: cpu, performance, temperature, cpu-speed

I have an [Intel Core i7-4770S (3.10 GHz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/75124/Intel-Core-i7-4770S-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) that can go up to 3.9 GHz in turbo mode. Windows Task Manager can report it going up to about 3.5 GHz when playing certain games and probably goes higher every once in a while in times where something's happening that I can't tab out of (that is, tab out of without crashing the game, i.e loading screens). Is it bad for a processor to be at that high a speed for extended periods of time or is it % utilization that matters most? Everything still works fine, and temperatures are good (about 45C CPU temperature from what I've seen). I just wouldn't want to add a significant amount of wear and tear to my computer.

Comment: Not if you change the oil on schedule.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Oh yeah, I always remember to brush my computer's teeth every day and give it a balanced diet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it’s not. Intel Turbo Boost is made so that power, current and temperature targets are not exceeded.

A little more info is available [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html). Be aware that some of it may be geared towards marketing rather than pure facts.

Answer (score 0):

If the temperature is correct and keep on that value it's most likely not a caused by to high temperture. Also the temperatur is fine for the CPU.